# Can the new results (about photonic time travel) make quantum computers feasible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

New results published about photonic time travel, [reference](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2014/140619/ncomms5145/full/ncomms5145.html) here make quantum computers a reality in the near future? These results seem to indicate that there can be qubits that can exhibit nonlinear behaviour, and this in turn may have deep implications to quantum cryptography, and possible profound effects on the nature of unitary interaction, and the influence of decoherence.